# 'Trace trick' for expectations of quadratic forms

Tags: matrices, statistics, expected-value, trace

I am trying to understand the proof for the [Kullback-Leibler divergence between two multivariate normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians). On the way, a sort of trace trick is applied for the expectation of the quadratic form $$E[ (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) ]= \operatorname{trace}(E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T)] \Sigma^{-1}),$$

where $x$ is MV-normal with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. The expectation is taken over $x$.

I would like to understand why this identity holds. I think more than one step is taken at once. I believe, $\operatorname{trace}(E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T] \Sigma^{-1})$ = $\operatorname{trace}(E[(x-\mu) \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)^T])$, but where does the trace come from?

Comment: The "trace trick" is the *cyclic* property of the trace operator: If the matrix products make sense, then $\operatorname{tr} (ABC) = \operatorname{tr}(CAB) = \operatorname{tr}(BCA)$.

Comment: Remember that a quadratic form is always a scalar (1x1 matrix).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Where does the trace come from?

A real number can be thought of as a $1 \times 1$ matrix, and its trace is itself. Thus
$$(x-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) = \operatorname{tr}\left((x-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\right)$$

> More than one step is taken at once.

After applying the above step, use the [cyclic property of the trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property) to obtain
$$\operatorname{tr}\left((x-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\right) = \operatorname{tr}\left((x-\mu)(x-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} \right)$$
By linearity of the trace operator, you can push the expectation inside
$$E \operatorname{tr}\left((x-\mu)(x-\mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1} \right) = \operatorname{tr}\left(E\left[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^\top\right] \Sigma^{-1} \right).$$

Answer (score 19):

To add to @angryavian's answer, you can swap expectation and trace because,
$$ tr(E[A]) = 
tr(\begin{bmatrix} E[a_{11}] & \dots & \\
\vdots & E[a_{22}] & \\
& & \ddots\end{bmatrix}) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N E[a_{ii}]=E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^N a_{ii}] = E[tr(A)] $$