# Distribution of Squared Euclidean Norm of Gaussian Vector

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}_N(\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{C})$ is an $N$-dimensional gaussian vector, where $\mathbf{m} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, what is the distribution of
$$
Y = \| \mathbf{X} \|^2
$$
where $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the $L_2$-norm (Euclidean norm) ?

It may be useful to know that the mean can be easily calculated via
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \| \mathbf{X} \|^2 ] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 \right] = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = \sum_{i=1}^N (\sigma^2_i + m_i^2) = \sum_{i=1}^N\sigma_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N m_i^2 = \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{C}) + \| \mathbf{m} \|^2
$$
where $\mathrm{tr}(\cdot)$ denotes the trace of a matrix.

EDIT: Related question: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255173/mean-of-squared-l-2-norm-of-gaussian-random-vector?rq=1).

Comment: By the way, the mean can also be calculated as $$\mathbb E[\| \mathbf X \|^2] = \mathbb E[\mathbf X^T \mathbf X] = \mathbb E[\text{tr}(\mathbf X \mathbf X^T)] = \text{tr}(\mathbb E[\mathbf X \mathbf X^T]) = \text{tr}(\mathbf C + \mathbb E[\mathbf X]\mathbb E[\mathbf X]^T) = \text{tr}(\mathbf C) + \mathbb E[\mathbf X]^T \mathbb E[\mathbf X]$$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $\mathbf{m}=0$ and $\mathbf{C}$ is the identity matrix, then $Y$ is (by definition) distributed according to a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

We can relax the assumption that $\mathbf{m}=0$ and obtain the [non-central chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).

On the other hand, if we maintain the assumption that $\mathbf{m}=0$ but allow for general $\mathbf{C}$, we have the [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution).

Finally, for general $(\mathbf{m},\mathbf{C})$, Y has a [generalised chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution).

Comment: Thank you! I needed the general $(\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{C})$ case. Can you please edit your answer by writing the CDF of the generalized chi-squared distribution? Or some other useful representation. The Wikipedia page doesn't have much information about it.

Comment: @PseudoRandom Unfortunately that's the extent of my knowledge on it! I'd suggest you start looking at the references on the Wikipedia page; that might get you somewhere. I'll try to have a look and update my answer if I find something helpful. Otherwise, you might also want to look at the latest edit to my answer, which might be of some help.

Comment: Thanks! In my specific case, $\mathbf{m} \neq \mathbf{0}$, but others may find your edit very useful. I will have a look at the references, thanks for that.

Comment: I think the last one is called 'non-central Wishart distribution' and the generalized $\chi^2$ refers to the sum of weighted $\chi^2$ with an additional normal distributed RV.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist how can $\Vert X\Vert_2^2$, a real number, have density of a Wishart distribution, which is defined on the set of positive definite matrices?!

Comment: Hello, just saw your answer, but I'm a bit confused about the part of the Wishart distribution, which seems to be the distribution of a certain types of random matrix, but here, the author asked for the distribution of a scalar quantity, namely the norm of a certain vector. What did I miss? Since Wishart distribution arises as the distribution of the sample covariance matrix for a sample from a multivariate normal distribution, should the squared norm of a MVN follow the trace of a Wishart distribution instead?