# Variance of the Norm of a Gaussian Random Vector

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

If $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}_N(\mathbf{m}, \mathbf{C})$ is an $N$-dimensional gaussian vector, where $\mathbf{m} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, what is the variance of
$$ Y=\|\mathbf{X}\|^2 $$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the $L_2$-norm (Euclidean norm) ?

As pointed out by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723181/distribution-of-squared-euclidean-norm-of-gaussian-vector), $Y$ has a generalised chi-squared distribution and its mean can be obtained easily. However, I want to know what is its variance. Can anybody please give some help?

Comment: Using [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/427332/119261), the variance is $\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf X^T \mathbf X)=2\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf C^2)+4\mathbf m^T \mathbf C \mathbf m$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for your reply! But do you know what is the mean and variance of the norm without squaring, i.e., $Y=\|\mathbf{X}\|$.

Comment: No. Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144893/119261.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathrm{Var}(Y) = \mathbb{E} Y^2 - (\mathbb{E} Y)^2$ and the latter is known, it boils down to computing $\mathbb{E} Y^2$. Now $Y^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^4 + \sum_{i \ne j} X_i^2 X_j^2$, so $\mathbb{E} Y^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E} X_i^4 + \sum_{i \ne j} \mathbb{E} X_i^2 X_j^2$. By putting in formulas for $\mathbb{E} X_i^4$ and $\mathbb{E} X_i^2 X_j^2$ using the fact $X \sim N(m, C)$ (the formulas for the moments on Wikipedia for the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and the [multivariate version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) might be helpful), you would be done after some hard algebraic work. For example, if we take $m = 0$ for simplicity, then $\mathbb{E} X_i^4 = 3 C_{ii}^2$ and $\mathbb{E} X_i^2 X_j^2 = C_{ii} C_{jj} + 2 C_{ij}^2$.

Comment: I suppose $Y^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^4+2\sum_{i \neq j} X_i^2 X_j^2$?

Comment: The notation $\sum_{i,j} X_i^2 X_j^2$ means we sum over all distinct pairs $(i, j)$, where order matters. E.g. we sum $X_1^2 X_2^2$ and $X_2^2 X_1^2$. If you like having a factor of $2$, then it is the same as $2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq N} X_i^2 X_j^2$ (note that this is different to what you wrote).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! BTW, do you know what is the mean and variance of the norm without squaring, i.e., $Y=\|\mathbf{X}\|$?

Answer (score 1):

$X\sim m+C^{1/2}Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,I_n).$ Write $C=U^TD^2U$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $D=\mathrm{diag}(c_1,\ldots,c_n).$ Since $UZ\sim Z$ we have $X\sim m+DZ.$ Denote $c=(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ and $mc=(m_1c_1,\ldots,m_nc_n).$
Therefore  $$Y\sim \|m\|^2+2\langle m,DZ \rangle +\|DZ\|^2=\|m\|^2+2\langle mc,Z \rangle +\|DZ\|^2$$ which implies
$$E(Y)=\|m\|^2+0+\|c\|^2=\|m\|^2+\mathrm{trace }\, C.$$ Next $$E(Y^2)= E\left((\|m\|^2+2\langle mc,Z \rangle +\|DZ\|^2)^2\right)=\|m\|^4+\|mc\|^2+2\|m\|^2\|c\|^2+E(\|DZ\|^4)$$ since the odd term $\langle mc,Z \rangle \times \|DZ\|^2$ has expectation $0.$ We are left with the calculation of
$$E(\|DZ\|^4)=3\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^4+2\sum_{i<j}c_i^2c_j^2=2\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^4+(\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2)^2=2\, \mathrm{trace }\, C^2+(\mathrm{trace }\, C)^2.$$
Finally (please check, I could have make mistakes)$$\sigma^2(Y)=\|mc\|^2+2\, \mathrm{trace }\, C^2.$$